# How do I install an OS on a server with multiple hard drives?

Tags: windows, hp-proliant

I have just acquired an old school server and want to set it up at home to tinker around with. It is a Compaq Proliant ML370 with a HP smart array 5300 hard drive redundancy system, with this it has six hard drives with identical data on each so if one fails you can swap it out and the system will be fine.

Now this server has windows server 2003 installed which is set up for a school system, it is still locked to the server admins account and I don't have the password. Do I have to wipe the server and reinstall windows or can i get around this? if so, how do I do it when I have so many hard drives?

Comment: It would depend on the RAID setup. Usually the raid controller should present your system with a lesser number of devices. In addition it's not as easy as just "swapping it out". You could probably use some method to access the Windows installation but you (probably) wouldn't be the owner of the License and as such shouldn't. Depending on what you want to install etc. you might have to supply drivers for the setup routine of whatever OS you're installation in order to recognize the RAID controller.

Comment: Thanks for that. so the best option is to wipe all the hard drives and start again. is it as simple as that?

Your saying that I cant simply boot and install windows server 2012 and it will run, i will need to find the drivers for the RAID controller somewhere to?

Comment: I'd probably wipe it, yes. You could just start the Server 2012 setup and have a look whenever you can select a partition (using the custom install option). If you can you should be fine. If you can't you probably need to find a driver.

Comment: Okay sounds good, Ill give it a shot thanks. Hopefully, I can work out the memory problem. Does all the memory need to be the same size and speed? across all slots?

Comment: You never said anything about a memory problem and should probably post it as an independent question.